# style modification with jquery different from css

Tags: jquery, css, styles

I'm applying the following styles to a div through jquery:

```
$("#content").css('width',$("#content").width()+'px');
$("#content").css('height',$("#content").height()+'px');
$("#content").css('position','fixed');
```

later in the script I'm removing the fixed position and the settings for height and width again.

I'm trying to do that by adding a class

```
.divStatic{
position:static;
height:auto;
width:auto;
}
$("#content").addClass('divStatic');
```

But that way the DIV keeps its fixed width.
If I do it with jquery, everything works fine.

```
$("#content").css('position','static');
$("#content").css('width','auto');
$("#content").css('height','auto');
```

Whats the difference?

Comment: You can't write JavaScript/jQuery in CSS.

Comment: _You can't write JavaScript/jQuery in CSS_ Did anyone try to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The noticable difference is in the priority of styles applied to the element by browser. Actual priority is:

1. inline element !important (:!important"...) - these are the top-priority styles
2. !important inside inline  block inside @media
3. !important inside inline  block
4. !important inside external css (@media declaration)
5. !important inside external css
6. inline element style declaration (:"...)
7. css declaration inside inline  block
8. css declarations inside external css styles (@media declaration)
9. css declarations inside external css styles
   And also there`s some more hierarchy elements according to your type of selector (selecting element in css by id has always higher priority, then selecting it by multiple classes, which has by itself higher priority than selecting element by a single class).

Your jQuery inline style declaration and it cannot be overriden by just adding class to your element.
I would recommend rewriting your js with something like this:

```
$("#content").css({'width':$("#content").width()+'px', 'height':$("#content").height()+'px', 'position':'fixed'});
$(document).on('*actionName*', '.elName', function(event){
  $("#content").removeAttr('style').addClass('divStatic');
});
```

Anyway, applying css directly with js is not really good practice. Try to avoid it. Consider using jQuery addClass instead and putt your styling inside external styles. (Exception - you can do it your way only if you really know what you're doing)

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically there is a hierarchy in CSS:

1. HTML properties (like `<div height="500px">`)
2. Element's css (like `<div style="color: blue;">`
3. css classes (like `<div class="divStatic>`)

Since the jQuery command adds the 2. one, you can't override it with a class, as the browser sees the first one as more important. (with the second $(...).css you override the first ones in the html itself)

There is a bit more to css priorities (like SITH-power and more) and you can easily find longer and better explanations to it, since you now know, why that happens.

To work around this, you could move the first css styles into a class, too and then make sure, they are less important than your .divStatic descriptions.